# 1998 Maxima keeps revving

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, maxima

When we hit about 25 MPH or more the car revs then stops, revs then stops, revs then stops. ND it only does this when we hit the gas not while at idle. Just replaced the air flow sensor and 2 others and it is still doing it. Adjusted the rim idle; tried everything I know how to do.

Comment: Are there any codes (CEL lit)? Have you checked for them at all?

Comment: What were the other two sensors?

Comment: If you are in the US can goto Autozone and they will hook up a tool to give you the diagnostic trouble codes or DTC's.  If you have those troublecodes someone here will be able to more effectively assist you in fixing the issue potentially.

Comment: My money is on a vacuum leak.

Comment: Going to check for codes asa I'll let YALL kno thanx

Comment: I'm assuming it's an automatic... have you checked the transmission fluid level?